# I installed Capistrano using MacPorts but capify can not find the capistrano gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capistrano, macports

Using MacPorts on OS X 10.7.5 I installed capistrano as follows:

```
[~] > install rb-capistrano
```

But when I run capify, I get the following error:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem capistrano (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
from /opt/local/bin/capify-1.8:18
```

This is clearly a bug with the MacPorts deployment of capistrano, ruby and gems, but is there a way I can work around the problem in the meantime? I just want Capistrano to work, I don't care about Ruby on Rails or anything Ruby at all.

Comment: I would definitely avoid using another package management system as a proxy for installing gems. Also, Ruby 1.8 has been end-of-lifed, and will no longer receive security updates; you should upgrade to Ruby 2.0 (or 1.9) immediately.

Comment: Sadly 1.8 is what you get when you `sudo port install ruby`. Thank you for the warning!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround: either install the gem manually, or use rvm to install it, bypassing MacPorts entirely.

I chose option 1: use "gem" to install Capistrano. This of course involved installing MacPorts gem and fixing the installation to actually work:

```
12:10 ~project ➤ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
12:10 ~project ➤ sudo port install rb-rubygems
12:11 ~project ➤ ln -s /opt/local/libexec/ruby1.8/gem /opt/local/bin/gem
12:11 ~project ➤ sudo gem install capistrano                                         
Successfully installed highline-1.6.19
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.6.7
Successfully installed net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0
Successfully installed capistrano-2.15.4
4 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for highline-1.6.19...
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.6.7...
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for capistrano-2.15.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for highline-1.6.19...
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.6.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for capistrano-2.15.4...
12:12 ~project ➤ which capify
/opt/local/bin/capify
12:12 ~project ➤ capify .
[add] making directory './config'
[add] writing './config/deploy.rb'
[add] writing './Capfile'
[done] capified!
```

As you can see, gem did the "right thing" for me by installing to the /opt/local/ (i.e.: MacPorts) directories.

This has been bug reported to MacPorts as https://trac.macports.org/ticket/39467

Comment: As @AndrewMarshall mentioned, using gem to install packages when using another package manager is A Bad Thing. In this case, cleaning up the mess is as simple as reinstalling MacPorts (i.e.: rm -rf /opt/local, then start from scratch). It's not like I'll be breaking MacPorts any more than it already is.